# If/Else jQuery: else statement not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

The *else* statement in this jQuery code is not working. I've tried placing the if/else statement into a function (after parsing through Stackoverflow), but I haven't been able to get this to work. Do you have any ideas as to what is the problem? Is this a syntax error?

Here's a [link to the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ezsufp8w/16/).

**jQuery**

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
    myAnswer();
  });

 $( "input" ).change(function() {
    myAnswer();
 });     

function myAnswer () {
    $(".pick").removeClass('my-display').addClass('my-no-display');
    var myPick = $("input").val();
    function myFinalAnswer () {
        if (myPick == "ram","mary","jon","shyam","shannon","tate","quy","sanjay") {
            var myString = "." + myPick; 
            var myFinalPick = myString.toLowerCase();
            $( myFinalPick).removeClass('my-no-display').addClass('my-display'); 
        }
        else {
            $(".none").removeClass('my-no-display').addClass('my-display');
        }
    }
    myFinalAnswer();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 top-line">
        <h2>Who will win the Game of Thrones?</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 my-choices">
        <p>Ram, Jon, Shyam, Shannon, Tate, Quy, Mary, or Sanjay?</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 my-input">
        <input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Take your best guess!') { this.value = ''; }" placeholder="Take your best guess!" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 my-button">
        <button class="submit-button">
            Submit
        </button>   
    </div>
</div>      
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 my-answer">
       <span class="mary pick my-no-display">We all love the walk of shame.</span>
        <span class="jon pick my-no-display">Isn't he too busy with tindr?</span>
        <span class="shyam pick my-no-display">We always knew his fingers were little.</span>
        <span class="shannon pick my-no-display">Because that's where a Khaleesi belongs.</span>
        <span class="tate pick my-no-display">Ramsey? Ewww.</span>
        <span class="quy pick my-no-display">What she said.</span>
        <span class="ram pick my-no-display">So into it!</span>
        <span class="sanjay pick my-no-display">Another Lannister?</span>
        <span class="none pick my-no-display">This is a terrible idea.</span>
    </div>          
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless it's a new ES6 statement I haven't learnt about, I don't think `myPick == "ram","mary","jon","shyam","shannon","tate","quy","sanjay"` does what you think.

Comment: The if/else is doing what it should. It's your syntax that's wrong.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ezsufp8w/18/

Comment: thanks so much. it was definitely the syntax and i fixed it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With jQuery, you could use the [`inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) function to check if a value is on a given array, for sample:

```
var myArray = ["ram","mary","jon","shyam","shannon","tate","quy","sanjay"];

if ($.inArray(myPick, myArray))
{
 // .. code 
}
```

Comment: @mary, dont forget to mark an answer(even if its not mine) as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to the answer

Answer (score 3):

Change your `if` statement to

```
if (["ram","mary","jon","shyam","shannon","tate","quy","sanjay"].indexOf(myPick) > -1)
```

Applying the same condition multiple times in an `if` statement does not work by seperating by comma. In this case, you can use `indexOf` which will return `-1` if it does not exist in the array.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  myAnswer();
});

$("input").change(function() {
  myAnswer();
});


function myAnswer() {
  $(".pick").removeClass('my-display').addClass('my-no-display');
  var myPick = $("input").val();

  function myFinalAnswer() {
    if (["ram", "mary", "jon", "shyam", "shannon", "tate", "quy", "sanjay"].indexOf(myPick) > -1) {
      var myString = "." + myPick;
      var myFinalPick = myString.toLowerCase();
      $(myFinalPick).removeClass('my-no-display').addClass('my-display');
    } else {
      alert("Hello else.");
      $(".none").removeClass('my-no-display').addClass('my-display');
    };
  }
  myFinalAnswer();
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}
input {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: grey;
  margin-left: 13px;
}
.top-line {
  text-align: center;
}
.my-choices {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.my-input {
  text-align: center;
}
.my-answer {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 8px 27px;
  width: 91%;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 1.7;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.my-answer {
  text-align: center;
}
.my-button {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
}
.submit-button {
  padding: 3px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-family: #A52A2A;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #666;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  width: 80%;
}
.my-display {
  display: inline;
}
.my-no-display {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 top-line">
      <h2>Who will win the Game of Thrones?</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 my-choices">
      <p>Ram, Jon, Shyam, Shannon, Tate, Quy, Mary, or Sanjay?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 my-input">
      <input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Take your best guess!') { this.value = ''; }" placeholder="Take your best guess!" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 my-button">
      <button class="submit-button">
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 my-answer">
      <span class="mary pick my-no-display">We all love the walk of shame.</span>
      <span class="jon pick my-no-display">Isn't he too busy with tindr?</span>
      <span class="shyam pick my-no-display">We always knew his fingers were little.</span>
      <span class="shannon pick my-no-display">Because that's where a Khaleesi belongs.</span>
      <span class="tate pick my-no-display">Ramsey? Ewww.</span>
      <span class="quy pick my-no-display">What she said.</span>
      <span class="ram pick my-no-display">So into it!</span>
      <span class="sanjay pick my-no-display">Another Lannister?</span>
      <span class="none pick my-no-display">This is a terrible idea.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand what you're trying with this line:

```
if (myPick == "ram","mary","jon","shyam","shannon","tate","quy","sanjay")
```

I think it's supposed to be:

```
if (myPick === "ram" || myPick === "mary" || myPick === "jon" || myPick === "shyam" || myPick === "shannon" || myPick === "tate" || myPick === "quy" || myPick === "sanjay")
```